# How to arrange some images vertically and horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

In my app i have 10 images, I arranged two images as row wise using a linear layout, I want to arrange the remaining images row wise (groups of two images) under the first row. I tried this code, I don't know how to arrange the remaining images under first row, I also want to add scroll view for the same. Is it possible to add a single scroll view for all linear layouts? I tried but the code is not working. Can anybody help me? I am new to android layouts.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.cozyne.user.picimagetest.GridViewActivity">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/gridimg" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/gridimg" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
   >
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/gridimg" />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/gridimg" />


</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use Gridview or RecyclerView using custom adapter intead.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

Add  android:layout_below to Second Row because your parent tag is RelativeLayout and In 
RelativeLayout you have to set child control by other control id.

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.cozyne.user.picimagetest.GridViewActivity">

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/firstrow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gridimg" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gridimg" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/secondrow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/firstrow"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
       >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gridimg" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gridimg" />


    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were using your layouts inconsistently. Put each set of two images into it's own Linear Layout and set it's orientation to horizontal. Then do so consistently for each subsequent row. You could also use a Table Layout with Table Rows as the rows. You should be setting the widths consistently and be sure to set the height to wrap content. If you're having trouble with inconsistent row heights, you can assign a height of 0dp to each row with a layout_weight of 1 to each row. However, that might distort/cutoff your images.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          tools:context="com.cozyne.user.picimagetest.GridViewActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gridimg" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gridimg" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gridimg" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gridimg" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add additional LinearLayouts below for each row that your want to include.

Comment: Change the top-level LinearLayout to a ScrollView if you want the entire screen to be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in TableLayout, you would modify it like this:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          tools:context="com.cozyne.user.picimagetest.GridViewActivity">



<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gridimg"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gridimg" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gridimg" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gridimg" />
</TableRow>

<!--add rows as needed-->

<!-- final row with one image-->
<TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:src="@drawable/gridimg" >
</TableRow>
```